# How to reduce major tick spacing on a matplotlib logarithmic plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to change the major tick label spacing to intervals of 0.1 (base 0.1) and have minor ticks (without labels) at 0.01 spacing for the code below (output shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yxmD.png).

```
x = np.array([1, 5, 10, 32])
y = np.array([0.34, 0.27, 0.25, 0.21])
yerr = np.array([0.02, 0.019, 0.019, 0.016])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
res = ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, fmt='.', ls='')

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

I've tried to do

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.LogLocator(base=0.01))
```

however nothing changes, which makes me think the base can not be less than 10.

Comment: It does change, but the values have to be above 1 to work.you should also show the grid on the plot for better visual.

Comment: In the plot that is produced by the code above, there are no major ticks on the y axis. You may get them via `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.LogLocator(base=10, subs=range(10)))`. What you see instead are the minor ticks. So I guess the question is how to get the minor ticks to be spaced by 0.01.

Comment: yes thanks, i have updated with a solution!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OK, the reasoning behind this is wrong ( & I misundertood the question)

This would add equidistant space between the ticks, definitely not you were asking.

```
plt.grid("on")  # Just to see the spacing more clearly
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.LogLocator(base=10**(1.0/1)))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(mtick.LogLocator(base=10**(1.0/10)))
```

(asuming 10 is the base of the log scale you're using and the fraction is how many more (or less) lines you want.

I did not understand how the decimal values in the 'base' variable work when using logarithmic scale.

---

Well, since you're working in logarithmic values ... that 'spacing' shouldn't be 1 or less. (using 1 you get an error) if you want to reduce spacing, just use a value between less than 10 (but more than 1).

In fact, using the line:

```
plt.grid("on")  # Just to see the spacing more clearly
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.LogLocator(base=10**(1/10)))
```

you get a tenth of a spacing than before.

It's all in how the vertical axes is computed when using the logarithmic scale.

Comment: Did you actually test what you are proposing here?

Comment: Then I do not understand the argument. You say you cannot use 1 as base, but then you use 10**(1./10), which is 1 as base. This is rather contraditory.

Comment: I just tested the 'base' value for LogLocator and it does work with values lower than 1 (I have to read how does this work) but it doesn't work with 1. And "10**(1./10)" is not 1, is ~1,2589

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Thanks ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the advice. My solution is to add this:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.LogLocator(base=10, subs=range(10)))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(mtick.LogLocator(base=10, subs=range(100)))
plt.setp(ax.get_yminorticklabels(), visible=False);
```